# Gluon Scene Builder does not launch (15.0.0-RC1.msi)

Tags: scenebuilder

I just downloaded SceneBuilder-15.0.0-RC1.msi from gluon website, installed it. When starting, nothing happens, no message whatsoever. When starting as administrator, basically the same, but I discovered in the installation folder a file is created named hs_err_pidxxxxx.log, containing the following

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=16520, tid=3752
#
# JRE version:  (15.0.1+9) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (15.0.1+9, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: --add-opens=javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml=ALL-UNNAMED --module-path=C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\app\mods com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz, 8 cores, 15G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 19041 (10.0.19041.662)
Time: Sun Jan 10 15:57:12 2021 Mitteleuropäische Zeit elapsed time: 0.051742 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000001fee94fb5f0):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=3752, stack(0x000000f58ac00000,0x000000f58ad00000)]

Stack: [0x000000f58ac00000,0x000000f58ad00000],  sp=0x000000f58acfea98,  free space=1018k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)


siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), data execution prevention violation at address 0x0000000000000000


Registers:
RAX=0x000001fee9c0fe08, RBX=0x000001fe86f28090, RCX=0x000001fee9c0fe08, RDX=0x000000000000034b
RSP=0x000000f58acfea98, RBP=0x000000f58acfebb0, RSI=0x000001fee9c0fdeb, RDI=0x000001fee9c0fdeb
R8 =0x000001fe86f28090, R9 =0x00000000000005ce, R10=0x000000f58acfeb10, R11=0x45f1c7cf10132c67
R12=0x00000000000005ce, R13=0x000001fee94fd810, R14=0x000001fee94fdb50, R15=0x000001fee94fdb50
RIP=0x0000000000000000, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000f58acfea98)
0x000000f58acfea98:   00007fff44431833 000001fe86f28090
0x000000f58acfeaa8:   00007fff44431877 00000000000005ce
0x000000f58acfeab8:   0000000000000000 000000f58acfeaf8
0x000000f58acfeac8:   0000000000000000 000001fee9c0fdeb
0x000000f58acfead8:   00007fff44431495 000001fe86f28090
0x000000f58acfeae8:   000000f58acfebb0 000001fee9c0fdeb
0x000000f58acfeaf8:   0000000000000000 000000f58acfebb0
0x000000f58acfeb08:   00007fff0471f74a 000000f5cafefafa
0x000000f58acfeb18:   000000000000034b 00000000000005ce
0x000000f58acfeb28:   ffffffff00000007 0000000086183d01
0x000000f58acfeb38:   00005831f7a63934 00000000000005ce
0x000000f58acfeb48:   000001fee94fdb50 000001fee94fbac0
0x000000f58acfeb58:   000001fee738cef0 0000000000525f03
0x000000f58acfeb68:   0000000000000368 000001fee9c0fdeb
0x000000f58acfeb78:   00007fff44431ed7 000001fe86717450
0x000000f58acfeb88:   0000000000000016 0000000000000001 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000000000000)
0xffffffffffffff00:   



---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x00007fff04affa50, length=0, elements={
}

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:
  0x000001fee954ee10 GCTaskThread "GC Thread#0" [stack: 0x000000f58ad00000,0x000000f58ae00000] [id=1668]
  0x000001fee9560520 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Main Marker" [stack: 0x000000f58ae00000,0x000000f58af00000] [id=1408]
  0x000001fee9561020 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Conc#0" [stack: 0x000000f58af00000,0x000000f58b000000] [id=684]
  0x000001fe865a40e0 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Refine#0" [stack: 0x000000f58b000000,0x000000f58b100000] [id=10684]
  0x000001fe865a4bf0 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Young RemSet Sampling" [stack: 0x000000f58b100000,0x000000f58b200000] [id=572]

=>0x000001fee94fb5f0 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=3752, stack(0x000000f58ac00000,0x000000f58ad00000)]

Threads with active compile tasks:

VM state: not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap address: 0x0000000700e00000, size: 4082 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Zero based, Oop shift amount: 3
CDS disabled.
Compressed class space mapped at: 0x0000000800000000-0x0000000840000000, size: 1073741824
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000800000000, Narrow klass shift: 0, Narrow klass range: 0x40000000

GC Precious Log:
 CPUs: 8 total, 8 available
 Memory: 16322M
 Large Page Support: Disabled
 NUMA Support: Disabled
 Compressed Oops: Enabled (Zero based)
 Heap Region Size: 2M
 Heap Min Capacity: 8M
 Heap Initial Capacity: 256M
 Heap Max Capacity: 4082M
 Pre-touch: Disabled
 Parallel Workers: 8
 Concurrent Workers: 2
 Concurrent Refinement Workers: 8
 Periodic GC: Disabled

Heap:
 garbage-first heap   total 262144K, used 0K [0x0000000700e00000, 0x0000000800000000)
  region size 2048K, 1 young (2048K), 0 survivors (0K)
 Metaspace       used 4K, capacity 4480K, committed 4480K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 3K, capacity 384K, committed 384K, reserved 1048576K

'''
```

(skipping rest of log file)
any ideas?

Comment: The .msi installer works for me. Can you try from command line? `cd C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder` and then `runtime\bin\java --add-opens javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml=ALL-UNNAMED -cp app\SceneBuilder-15.0.0-all.jar com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp`

Comment: Yes this command will start SceneBuilder, but using SceneBuilder.exe does not

Comment: Maybe related to an antivirus? The exe is mainly calling the same command line.

Comment: can't think of any antivirus, I just have windows 10 running, strange then

Comment: Try uninstalling, download and install again, make sure you accept all the Windows security dialogs... If still doesn't work, you could create a batch file to execute the above command line.

Comment: Played around, still the same, I leave it there now. SceneBuilder.exe does not launch the program, but given command does, thanks!

Comment: I'm late to the party, but I was having this same issue. Creating a shortcut to `C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\runtime\bin\java` and then adding the arguments to that seems to work. Set the shortcut target to `"C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\runtime\bin\java.exe" --add-opens javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml=ALL-UNNAMED -cp app\SceneBuilder-15.0.0-all.jar com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp` and the 'Start in to `"C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder"`

Comment: Thanks for reporting. This is related to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8254920